# find the sum of many numbers according to one string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work with this file :

```
Germanwings Frankfurt 163
NorwegianAir Bergen 202
Wizzair London 184 //<----This
Wizzair Frankfurt 83 //<----This
Wizzair Lisbon 198 //<----This
```

my code should print out the name of one string **(the flight with the most total number of passenger)**
and its total just like that **184 + 83 + 198 = 465**

```
Wizzair  465
```

here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
df = sorted(df)
route = ''
totals = {}
for route,flights in zip(df['Airline'],df['Flights']):
    airline,*rest = route.split()
    if airline not in totals:
        totals[airline] = 0
        totals[airline] += flights
        print(airline,flights)
```

**the error** :

```
 from collections import counter
ImportError: cannot import name 'counter' from 'collections' (C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I didn't import any counter I didn't use collections why it return this error ???

**do u have any idea please**

Comment: Update Pandas to the latest version.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Why?

Comment: Counter has a capital C.

Comment: Show a stack trace.

Comment: @ Susmit Agrawal it's already updated dude I just installed it

Comment: Can you please show the entire traceback? Your code doesn't use ``from collections import counter``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your version of `pandas` isn't compatible with your version of Python?

The easy fix is to not use it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

totals = defaultdict(int)
with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        if len(line.split()) != 3:
            continue
        [airline, _route, passengers] = line.split()
        totals[airline] += int(passengers)
print("%s  %d" % max(totals.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1]))
```

Comment: you were right bro  it worked perfectly . thank you

Answer (score 0):

one of your modules is using collections as a dependency

the correct name is Counter, you could probably edit the requirement within the package.

```
from collections import Counter
```

Comment: I did it and I still have the same Error dude